# Construct a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone give me a hint on how to construct a complex function that is only differentiable on the curve $y=x^2$ using the Cauchy-Riemann conditions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to satisfy the Cauchy–Riemann equations we need

$$u_x=v_y$$
$$u_y=-v_x$$

therefore we can find a set of conditions so that $u_x=v_y$ is always satisfied while $u_y=-v_x$ is satisfied only on the curve $y=x^2$. As $y-x^2=0$ we see that

$$ u_y+v_x=y-x^2$$
$$u_x=v_y=0$$

would satisfy these conditions. Letting $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ we have

$$u_x(x,y)=0,~~~~u_y(x,y)=y$$
$$v_x(x,y)=-x^2,~~~~v_y(x,y)=0$$

from which we can integrate to find a suitable value for $f(x+iy)$.